# Getting I/flutter ( 5127): 403 when trying to connect a remote API based on Laravel on a shared server. Same API working fine with Postman

Tags: flutter, http, http-status-code-403

I am not an expert in flutter development and I am facing this strange issue.

I have an API hosted on a shared server based on Laravel, which is working fine with post man. But when I try to send auth request to it from Flutter it returns I/flutter ( 5127): 403. Which when I search through internet says I don't have permission to access the page which is not the case

My code

```
var url = Uri.parse(url_to_api);
    var data = jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'email': emailController.text,
      'password': passwordController.text,
      'device_name': 'Mobile'
    });
    var headers = <String, String>{
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    };
    var response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: headers);
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var parsedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var authToken = parsedJson['token'];
      await FlutterKeychain.put(key: 'auth_token', value: authToken);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyDashboard()));
    } else {
      EasyLoading.showToast('Error connecting to server');
    }
  }
```

the response is I/flutter ( 5127): 403

What can I try in order to resolve this?